# To justify whether or not jointly Gaussian

Tags: summation

Let $X_{1}$,..., $X_{n}$ be random variables, and define 
$$Y_{k} := \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_{i}, k = 1,...,n.$$
Suppose that $Y_{1}$,..., $Y_{n}$ are jointly Gaussian. Determine whether or not $X_{1}$,...,$X_{n}$ are jointly Gaussian.

I do not know how to solve it!

Comment: Hint : use a linear transformation to relate the Y and X variables, then relate their laws. Dedcue that one of them being jointly gaussian should imply the other one being jointly gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

$(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=(Y_1,Y_2-Y_1,...,Y_n-Y_{n-1})$. This implies that $X_i$'s are jointly Gaussian.

Comment: can you give me a more detailed explanation? what does jointly Gaussian exactly mean?

Comment: @givan Jointly Gaussian random variables are those whose densities have as specific form but it can be shown that $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is jointly Gaussian iff every linear combination of $X_i$" has a normal distribution on the real line.

Comment: How can I understand "every linear combination of $X_{i}$'' has a nornal distribution on the real line", especially the real line. How do $X_{i}$ correlate to the $Y_{i} - Y_{i-1}$? Because I cannot find the definition of jointly Gaussian.

Comment: If you do not know what jointly Gaussian means you should search the net for either 'jointly Gaussian' or 'multi-dimensional Gaussian /normal distribution'.  @givan